# how to handle session management and cookies in watin

Tags: c#, session, testing, watin, session-cookies

I have a website where i have to perform some tests, 
but once i login in to pages and try to get the cookies, using this code, i get cookies count as 0.

```
newbrowser.GetCookiesForUrl(tempurl)
```

I was thinking to store the cookies in a list,

so that when i close the browser, i can set the cookies 
by `IE.SetCookie()`

But i was unable to find any cookies in any url, once i close my browser again i have to login manually, 
is there any way to go around with this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you get all cookies for current document:

```
string cookies = browser.Eval("document.cookie");
```